# What does the term "new found glory" mean?

Tags: meaning

What does the term mean?

A reference below:

> I was mowing away, basking in my **new-found glory**, and suddenly I was saying a prayer.

https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=XzX4vu5ACyAC&pg=PA29&dq=%22new+found+glory%22&hl=zh-TW&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22new%20found%20glory%22&f=false

Answer (score 1):

It means that the glory he was basking in was, at the time he was basking in it, according to this sentence, new to him; he had only recently found this glory when he began mowing his lawn.

Comment: Does that literally mean a new glory in his life or something more mundane?